# Awk or Sed to join multiple lines separated with blank line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I managed to create a file which now needs to be formatted for csv import:

Here are some records:

```
(202) 111-0000
1
Full Name
Street Address
City, State ZIP

(212) 222-9999
2
Full Name
Street Address
City, State ZIP

(312) 888-2222
3
Full Name
Street Address
City, State ZIP
```

etc

I am looking to transpose into this:

```
(202) 111-0000,1,Full Name,Street Address,City,State,ZIP
(212) 222-9999,2,Full Name,Street Address,City,State,ZIP
(312) 888-2222,3,Full Name,Street Address,City,State,ZIP
```

Notice how City State and ZIP have been properly comma delimited in the desired output.

Any awk or sed gurus willing to help me out with this?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Have you tried doing it yourself ? What's the problem you faced ?
Please show research/effort so that SO users can help out.

Comment: Hi. I did manage to do it myself (in a very ugly way) while waiting for notification - which I got with all 4 answers in a single email an hour ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you have access to GNU awk and sed.

In order to get the ZIP part right, let's use this as the sample input:

```
$ cat file
(202) 111-0000
1
Full Name
Street Address
City, State 10023

(212) 222-9999
2
Full Name
Street Address
City, State 10023

(312) 888-2222
3
Full Name
Street Address
City, State 10023
```

We can transpose that as follows:

```
$ awk -v RS="" -F'\n' -v OFS=, '{$1=$1} 1' file | sed -r 's/ +([[:digit:]-]+)$/, \1/'
(202) 111-0000,1,Full Name,Street Address,City, State, 10023
(212) 222-9999,2,Full Name,Street Address,City, State, 10023
(312) 888-2222,3,Full Name,Street Address,City, State, 10023
```

#### Eliminating the extra spaces

If the extra spaces above are a problem, try:

```
$ awk -v RS="" -F'\n' -v OFS=, '{$1=$1} 1' file | sed -r 's/ +([[:digit:]-]+)$/, \1/; s/, +/,/g'
(202) 111-0000,1,Full Name,Street Address,City,State,10023
(212) 222-9999,2,Full Name,Street Address,City,State,10023
(312) 888-2222,3,Full Name,Street Address,City,State,10023
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/\n(\S)/,\1/;ta;s/,\s+/,/g;P;d' file
```

Replace newlines by commas unless the line begins with a space, in which case remove any spaces following commas and print the front line ditching the empty line.

Answer (score 0):

A short `awk` solution (gives an extra `,` at the end)

```
awk 'NR%6==5 {gsub(/,? /,",")} ORS=NR%6?",":RS' file
(202) 111-0000,1,Full Name,Street Address,City,State,ZIP,
(212) 222-9999,2,Full Name,Street Address,City,State,ZIP,
(312) 888-2222,3,Full Name,Street Address,City,State,ZIP,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gsed -n 'H;/^$/h;/ZIP$/x;s/^\n//;s/\n/,/gp' file
```

- **-n**
  close pattern space default print.
- **H**
  current line append to hold space.
- **/ZIP$/x**
  when current line has *"ZIP"* keyword, exchange hold space and pattern space. **Now pattern space has a *"ZIP"* line, and this *"ZIP"* line has already append to hold space by command *'H'*, we must empty hold space before next circle**.
- **/^$/h** 
  when meets blank line, pattern space append to hold space, it will empty the hold space.
- **s/\n/,/gp** 
  do substitute in pattern space and then print the result.